# Applying QGraphicView transform to saved image

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qgraphicsview, qpixmap

Let's say I have a `QPixmap` loaded in a `QGraphicsView` that has been scaled by a factor of 2, so that the image is now clipped on all sides. I would like to take the clipped image and save it as a new image file so that it matches what is seen in the `QGraphicsView`.  I know that `QPixmap` has a save() function but without reapplying the view transform it won't differ from the original.

How can this be accomplished? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewport()` is the widget that is displayed visually in the `QGraphicsView`, so you must save an image of that widget with `render()`.

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
view.setScene(scene)
scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("/path/of/image"))
view.scale(4, 4)
view.show()

pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(view.viewport().size())
view.viewport().render(pixmap)
pixmap.save("test.png")

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ahhhh! Nice! Never would have occurred to me, Thank you very, very much!